# Fill table with data based on other table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 2 tables in Oracle database: `document` and `document_closure`.

**document:**

```
- id
- name
- parent_id
```

**document_closure:**

```
- id
- parent_id
- child_id
- level
```

`document` table has a lot of data (10k~20k). `document_closure` is empty.

**Question**: How to fill `document_closure` table with data based on `document` table. What sql script needs to be my that task?

Lets say I have such tree. **Example:**

```
A
|
 - B
   |
    - C
```

**document** table:

```
id | parent_id | name
1  |           | A
2  | 1         | B
3  | 2         | C
```

Finally **document_closure** must be:

```
id | parent_id | child_id | level
1  | 1         | 1        | 0
2  | 2         | 2        | 0
3  | 3         | 3        | 0
4  | 1         | 2        | 1
5  | 2         | 3        | 1
6  | 1         | 3        | 2
```

Comment: Create a view document_closure instead.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Also, in database applications, you would normally run a query to join/combine/process/filter data from existing tables and use the data at that time. Is there a particular reason you need to create a table with that data? A requirement for persistence of those results? The issue will be that if data in any of the dependent tables changes, your new table will be out of date until you run your procedure again.

Answer (score 2):

While **parent_id** and **name** fields in **document_closure** are the same coming from **document** table, you didn't mention what to put in the **name** field...
However assuming you can use the same (or null) value for the **name** field you just need an *INSERT INTO SELECT* statement like this

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...) SELECT column1, column2, column3, ... FROM table1 WHERE condition;
```

that copies data from document table and inserts them into document_closure table. In your case you just need the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO document_closure (id,parent_id) SELECT id,parent_id FROM document;
```

and you'll have all your records in document table copied in document_closure table.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done USING Oracle's `connect by` for hierarchical queries. This comes with a number of handy functions, including `level` to indicate how far down the hierarchy you are and `connect_by_root()` which returns the root value of the hierarchy (i.e. the top level value).

The query to generate the data based on the documents table looks something like:

```
WITH documents AS (SELECT 1 ID, NULL parent_id, 'A' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 2 ID, 1 parent_id, 'B' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 3 ID, 2 parent_id, 'C' NAME FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking a table with your sample data in it.
-- Since you already have this table, you don't need to bother defining the above subquery.
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY LEVEL, connect_by_root(ID), ID) ID,
       connect_by_root(ID) parent_id,
       ID child_id,
       LEVEL -1 lvl
FROM   documents d
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = parent_id;

        ID  PARENT_ID   CHILD_ID        LVL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1          0
         2          2          2          0
         3          3          3          0
         4          1          2          1
         5          2          3          1
         6          1          3          2
```